# How to get the value of a Flow outside a coroutine?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-flow

How can I get the value of a Flow outside a coroutine similarly to LiveData?

```
// Suspend function 'first' should be called only from a coroutine or another suspend function
flowOf(1).first()
```

```
// value is null
flowOf(1).asLiveData().value
```

```
// works
MutableLiveData(1).value
```

**Context**

I'm avoiding `LiveData` in the repository layer in favor of `Flow`. Yet, I need to set, observe and collect the value for immediate consumption. The later is useful for authentication purpose in a OkHttp3 `Interceptor`.

Comment: `asLiveData` creates a LiveData that starts its own coroutine to collect the values from the Flow. The initial value of `value` in your example above would be `null` because there hasn't been a chance for the coroutine to start yet.

Comment: The point of Flow is to use it for getting data that is too time-consuming to do synchronously, so you would never want to get a value from it without a coroutine.

Comment: @Tenfour04 it is null indeed. I'm not exposing LiveData from the repository layer as pointed out by CommonsWare in many answers. Yet I need observability.

Comment: There is no "value of a Flow". `LiveData` is a value holder, so it has a value (or `null`) at any point in time. `Flow` is just a stream. A `BroadcastChannel` is the coroutines equivalent of a value holder with observability, though that's still labeled as an experimental API IIRC.

Comment: @CommonsWare thank you for your comment. Would you say it is acceptable in this case to expose a LiveData object in the repository?

Comment: If your interceptor can deal with `null`, you can use `LiveData` or `BroadcastChannel` or just having the repository keep a cache of the last-received value and return it via a separate function. If your interceptor cannot deal with `null`, then you need to add a separate blocking API to the repository that your interceptor can use, or try consuming the `Flow` using `first()` inside `runBlocking()` to force synchronous behavior.

Comment: OK, I adapted my comments into an answer. While writing it, it dawned on me that my suggestion of `Flow` with `runBlocking()` may or may not be practical, depending on what this `Flow` is, how it gets its data, etc. So I can't give you a clean out-of-the-box solution for the scenario where your interceptor must have the data.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Well... what you're looking for isn't really what `Flow` is for. `Flow` is just a stream. It is not a value holder, so there is nothing for you to retrieve.

So, there are two major avenues to go down, depending on what your interceptor needs.

Perhaps your interceptor can live without the data from the repository. IOW, you'll use the data if it exists, but otherwise the interceptor can continue along. In that case, you can have your repository emit a stream but also maintain a "current value" cache that your interceptor can use. That could be via:

- `BroadcastChannel`
- `LiveData`
- a simple property in the repository that you update internally and expose as a `val`

If your interceptor needs the data, though, then none of those will work directly, because they will all result in the interceptor getting `null` if the data is not yet ready. What you would need is a call that *can* block, but perhaps evaluates quickly if the data is ready via some form of cache. The details of that will vary a lot based on the implementation of the repository and what is supplying the `Flow` in the first place.

Comment: Room is supplying the `Flow` in the first place. I use Room as a persistent storage for the current user and token.

Comment: @maxbeaudoin: OK, then, the crudest-possible implementation would be to add a separate blocking DAO function that your repository in turn exposes, that the interceptor uses.

Comment: Thank you. I have much to consider.

Comment: @CommonsWare, Won't making a new dao (query call to DB) more resource extensive than getting from already available Flow<List<Item>>?

Comment: @CyberAvater: A `Flow` isn't "already available", as a `Flow` does not hold anything. It is a stream, nothing more. It is not a value holder, so there is nothing for you retrieve. Certain *types* of flows, such as a `StateFlow`, hold state, but that's not part of the question.

Answer (score 41):

You can do this

```kotlin
val flowValue: SomeType
runBlocking(Dispatchers.IO) {
    flowValue = myFlow.first()
}
```

Yes its not exactly what Flow was made for.

But its not always possible to make everything asynchronous and for that matter it may not even always be possible to 'just make a synchronous method'. For instance the current Datastore releases (that are supposed to replace shared preferences on Android) do only expose Flow and nothing else. Which means that you will very easiely get into such a situation, given that none of the Lifecycle methods of Activities or Fragments are coroutines.

If you can help it you should always call coroutines from suspend functions and avoid making `runBlocking` calls. A lot of the time it works like this. But it´s not a surefire way that works all the time. You can introduce deadlocks with `runBlocking`.

Comment: Thanks for the warnings. To add on this, with `runBlocking` you are likely to block the UI Main thread, which should be avoided if at all possible.

Comment: I precisely got stuck in a datastore preferences situation I needed a value and it's in a flow.

Answer (score 4):

To get the value of a Flow outside of a coroutine, the best option is to create the flow as a StateFlow and then call the value property on the StateFlow.

```
class MyClass {
   private val mutableProperty = MutableStateFlow(1)
   val property = mutableProperty.asStateFlow()

   ...
   mutableProperty.value = 2
}
...

val readProperty = MyClass().property.value
val propertyAsFlow = MyClass().property as Flow<Int>
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use something like this:

```
    fun <T> SharedFlow<T>.getValueBlockedOrNull(): T? {
        var value: T?
        runBlocking(Dispatchers.Default) {
            value = when (this@getValueBlockedOrNull.replayCache.isEmpty()) {
                true -> null
                else -> this@getValueBlockedOrNull.firstOrNull()
            }
        }
        return value
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [MutableStateFlow](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/-mutable-state-flow/) and [MutableSharedFlow](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/-mutable-shared-flow/) for emitting the data from coroutine and receiving the data inside `Activity/Fragment`. `MutableStateFlow` can be used for state management. It requires default value when initialised. Whereas `MutableSharedFlow` does not need any default value.

But, if you don't want to receive stream of data, (i.e) your API call sends data only once, you can use suspend function inside coroutine scope and the function will perform the task and return the result like synchronous function call.

Comment: How? Need a good code sample.